# Read power of an exponential in sympy

Tags: python, encryption, sympy, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement an encryption scheme described [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1401/1401.5787.pdf) which uses orthogonal matrices and the exponential function to both encrypt and decrypt a text. I am recreating their results exactly and then changing from there. My main problem is I just have no idea how I can read the desired exponential to store in an array.

Comment: The code is incomplete: `NameError: name 'encodedtext_pad' is not defined`

Comment: Added, sorry about that!

Comment: The paper proposing this cipher is rather strange and confusing, In particular, it talks about private and public keys, but then uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt messages. It also seems to assume that a real number can be uniquely represented in the form a*e^k which is not true. There are a lot of better researched and explained cryptosystems, I would rather steer away from this one.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more @bb1 but unfortunately it was assigned as a project in a linear algebra class. I suspect that when they say C is made up of a private and public key that both keys are two orthogonal matrices, and so their product is also orthogonal. This is how I implemented it originally, but after getting confusing results I decided to try to just replicate the results in the paper instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the exponents of E from an expression like this:

```
>>> from sympy import exp
>>> eq =21*exp(18)+15*exp(3)
>>> [i.args[0] for i in eq.atoms(exp)]
[3, 18]
```

`exp` is a function with one arg; SymPy objects with args use the attribute `args` to indicate what arguments were used to create the object.